# ezpublis 5.x public api to get current user draft

Tags: ezpublish

In legacy stack there was a function to fetch current users drafts.
https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Modules/content/Fetch-functions/draft_version_list

In ezpublish 5.x there is a similar method in rest api  `loadUserDrafts($userId)`.
eZ\Publish\Core\REST\Server\Controller\User.php

I want similar function for Public API. Is it available?

Answer (score 3):

you can find this function within the `content.service` of the repository.

The method you are looking for is `loadContentDrafts` which takes a `User` as the first parameter and returns the drafts assigned to this user.

Hope this is what you are looking for.